# How to run a command automatically after completing download?

Tags: command-line, firefox, downloads

I need a way that helps me to run a command automatically after a download completes.

I want to create a directory beside the downloaded file automatically after I clicked on the integrated download button from Firefox. I want all of those to be automatic.

Comment: I think this hasn't got much to do with Ubutnu. Just search for a addon which executes a command after completing a download.

Comment: What would be the purpose of the newly created directory and what would the command exactly need to do?

Comment: that was just an example to explain my problem. actually I want to learn "the way" to run any command after download completed, not only such a thing like creating a directory!

Comment: wget has that option...

Answer (score 1):

If you can download the file outside of Firefox, you can use

```bash
filetodownload=file-to-download.ext
wget http://www.example.org/"$filetodownload" -O "$filetodownload"
#"I want to create a directory beside the downloaded file automatically"
#You didn't specify a dir name
mkdir "$filetodownload"
```

Otherwise, you'll have to monitor the file's download progress and when it's finished, make the directory "beside the downloaded file". The following worked for me (but I couldn't make a dir with the same name as the file). It looks at all files though, including hidden ones. Modify as needed.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
 do
  for files in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin -1 -type f)
   do
    testbefore=$(ls -l $files | awk '{print $5$6$7$8$9}')
    sleep 2
    testafter=$(ls -l $files | awk '{print $5$6$7$8$9}')
    if [ $testbefore = $testafter ]
     then
#     echo $testbefore
     mkdir $(basename "$files")_
    fi
   sleep 5
  done
 done
```

Comment: I don't understand the first line of the first method! what is it?

Comment: That's a variable. When you assign a value to a variable, you can just do var=value. When you want to use it later in the script or command-line session, you prefix it with a '$'. If you paste that into Notepad++ and set the "Language" to "Shell", it will colorize the keywords. It makes it easier to see what's what.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add mime type to `neverAsk.openFile` in `about:config` (you can add `*/*` for all)
2. Create an executable script that:

   - takes the file path from the arguments list (the first argument)
   - moves it to target location (as it has been downloaded to `tmp`)
   - runs whatever commands you want
3. Tell Firefox to open this file type with your script

This last one is easy to do in `about:preferences` but little harder if you want to manually add records to `mimeTypes.rdf` file in Firefox's profile.

Comment: It doesn't work any more. I checked on Firefox `41.0.2`, `44.0` and `47.0`. It seems like a bug in Firefox. The checkbox "do this automatically for files like that from now on" works for `Save File` but does not work for `Open with` download dialog option any more.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox downloads a file under a tempory name $f.part and if download is completed renames it to $f.

So you can watch for directory changes with tools like `inotifywait` or [watchmedo](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/).

```
inotifywait -m .
...
./ MOVED_FROM file.zip.part
./ MOVED_TO file.zip
```